# Sending mail using PHP even if the browser is closed by client

Tags: php, email, browser, send

I am making an eCommerce website.

If the client leaves the process of shopping with only one item in cart and clicks the checkout process then I need to send an email even if the browser is closed.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will have better luck on RentaCoder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track user on the page, to be able to tell, when the user closes the browser. Relying on the client side script (JavaScript in the browser) to inform you that user just close the browser is not enough.

Just perform AJAX requests every eg. 10 seconds and if you will not get any information from users browser for eg. couple minutes, you can assume the browser has been closed and you can send an email.

Comment: thank you for your answer.Really I didn;t understand .Can u pls give small example

Comment: @vijayalakshmi: The example is really your site-dependent and involves: 1) storing transaction server side (which you already do according to your question), 2) storing time stamp of the last activity on the client side (stored in the transaction data), 3) calling the site with AJAX (take a look at JavaScript's setInterval() and jQuery's $.post()) to make it update the times tamp stored in point 2., 4) regularly checking the database for transactions that weren't completed nor updated in last couple minutes (which indicates the user probably close the browser, the system or lost connection).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a task in database when user clicked checkout button. Then you can run cronjob to iterate all over the tasks and send emails. Or you can use task queue mechanism like Celery - https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php http://celeryproject.org/